# Linker error when compiling iPhone app for Simulator using OGRE libraries

Tags: objective-c, linker, ios-simulator, ogre3d

I'm trying to build an iPhone app using the OGRE framework, and I'm getting a linker error when building for the simulator that I'm not sure how to fix.

I created the Xcode project using the OGRE iPhone template.  I'm using the static libraries for OGRE from the main website, `Ogre_iOS_4.0_Dependencies_20100623`, and trying to build for the iOS 4.1 Simulator.  I'm building with Xcode 3.2.4 on Mac OS X 10.6.4.

Compilation seems to work fine, but when it gets to the link stage, I get the following errors:

```
Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OgreTestApp.app/OgreTestApp normal i386
cd /Users/pauly/Projects/workspaces/games/OgreTestApp
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk -L/Users/pauly/Projects/workspaces/games/OgreTestApp/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/pauly/Projects/sdk/Ogre/OgreSDK-iPhone/lib/release -L/Users/pauly/Projects/sdk/Ogre/OgreSDK-iPhone/iPhoneDependencies/lib/release -F/Users/pauly/Projects/workspaces/games/OgreTestApp/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/pauly/Projects/workspaces/games/OgreTestApp/build/OgreTestApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OgreTestApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/OgreTestApp.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread -lFreeImage -lFreeType -lOIS -lzzip -lOgreMainStatic -lRenderSystem_GLESStatic -lPlugin_BSPSceneManagerStatic -lPlugin_OctreeSceneManagerStatic -lPlugin_ParticleFXStatic -o /Users/pauly/Projects/workspaces/games/OgreTestApp/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OgreTestApp.app/OgreTestApp

ld: warning: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)has different visibility (default) in /Users/pauly/Projects/sdk/Ogre/OgreSDK-iPhone/lib/release/libOIS.a(OISInputManager.o) and (hidden) in /Users/pauly/Projects/workspaces/games/OgreTestApp/build/OgreTestApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OgreTestApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/OgreFramework.o
ld: warning: std::_Rb_tree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::_M_create_node(std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&)has different visibility (default) in /Users/pauly/Projects/sdk/Ogre/OgreSDK-iPhone/lib/release/libOIS.a(OISInputManager.o) and (hidden) in /Users/pauly/Projects/workspaces/games/OgreTestApp/build/OgreTestApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OgreTestApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/OgreFramework.o
ld: warning: std::char_traits<char>::eq(char const&, char const&)has different visibility (hidden) in /Users/pauly/Projects/sdk/Ogre/OgreSDK-iPhone/lib/release/libFreeImage.a(IPTC.o) and (default) in /Users/pauly/Projects/sdk/Ogre/OgreSDK-iPhone/lib/release/libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreString.o)
ld: warning: std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)has different visibility (hidden) in /Users/pauly/Projects/sdk/Ogre/OgreSDK-iPhone/lib/release/libFreeImage.a(IPTC.o) and (default) in /Users/pauly/Projects/sdk/Ogre/OgreSDK-iPhone/lib/release/libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreScriptCompiler.o)
Undefined symbols:
  ".objc_class_name_NSAutoreleasePool", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSAutoreleasePool in libRenderSystem_GLESStatic.a(OgreEAGLWindow.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIApplication", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIApplication in libOIS.a(iPhoneInputManager.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIWindow", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIWindow in libRenderSystem_GLESStatic.a(OgreEAGLWindow.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIView", referenced from:
      .objc_class_name_InputDelegate in libOIS.a(iPhoneInputManager.o)
      .objc_class_name_EAGLView in libRenderSystem_GLESStatic.a(OgreEAGLWindow.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIAccelerometer", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIAccelerometer in libOIS.a(iPhoneInputManager.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIAccelerometer in libOIS.a(iPhoneAccelerometer.o)
  ".objc_class_name_CAEAGLLayer", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CAEAGLLayer in libRenderSystem_GLESStatic.a(OgreEAGLWindow.o)
  ".objc_class_name_EAGLContext", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@EAGLContext in libRenderSystem_GLESStatic.a(OgreEAGLESContext.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSDictionary", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSDictionary in libRenderSystem_GLESStatic.a(OgreEAGLWindow.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSNumber", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNumber in libRenderSystem_GLESStatic.a(OgreEAGLWindow.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIScreen", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIScreen in libOIS.a(iPhoneInputManager.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIScreen in libRenderSystem_GLESStatic.a(OgreEAGLSupport.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIScreen in libRenderSystem_GLESStatic.a(OgreEAGLWindow.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I fix this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need correct precompiled Ogre dependencies for correct iOS SDK version (Masterfalcon regularly publish those dependencies on the ogre3d.org).
Similar linker errors often caused by incorrect iPhoneDependencies (build for older iPhoneSKD that you have).

Just follow the instructions as listed here: 
http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Building+Ogre+with+CMake
Secion "Configuring for iPhone".
All should build fine.